# I get 'deprecated' warnings in Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ambiguous.dubbelzinnig.com/index.php?    get_cat=1"];

NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];

if (jsonData == nil) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Webservice Down" message:@"The webservice you are accessing is down. Please try again later."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else {...
```

It appears that initWithContentsOfURL needs to be changed, but I have tried what it said in the developer's guide, but I cannot get it to work...can somebody fix this code please?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why don't you describe what you tried to do and how exactly it didn't work?

Comment: Whenever you get a deprecated warning, you should look at the documentation to see what it suggests you use instead.  A quick way to do this is to hold the option key down and click on the method.

Answer (score 2):

Use `initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` or `initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` instead.

For example:

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ambiguous.dubbelzinnig.com/index.php?get_cat=1"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if( error == nil ) {
    // Parse jsonData
} else {
    // There was a problem
}
```

You'll want to replace the encoding value with an enum for the actual encoding type.  There are many enums for this purpose available in the NSString class... see the "String Encodings" section in: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but then Xcode complains that encoding and error are undefined!  Please someone help and fix this code....

Comment: @user1836591Edited my answer with an example.  You'll need to set the encoding to the actual encoding of the document.

Comment: You are great!  It works...now I see what they wanted me to do...Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithContentsOfURL%3a)?

> **initWithContentsOfURL:**
>
> Initializes the receiver, a newly allocated NSString object, by reading data
>   from the location named by a given URL. (Deprecated in OS X v10.4. Use
>   **initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:** or
>   **initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:** instead.)

Comment: @user1836591 Dont say it doesn't help you. first say what you have tried from sidyll suggested and what error you got. He suggested from documentation. Its not gonna be wrong in anyway. Its about what have you tried..